# Migrate Apache Camel Endpoints

Tags: migration, apache-camel, endpoint

I have recently started with Apache Camel so apologies if this questions is silly.

I have 2 processes A and B, and each process has an endpoint E1 and E2 respectively. Now let's imagine that I need to create a process C and that process B has to die. Can I migrate E2 to C and connect it through a route to E1 in process A?

It is important to notice that A, B and C may be in different machines as well.

I google for process migration in Camel, but all I found were articles referring to JBoss Fuse:

- [Migrating Endpoints](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Implementing_Enterprise_Integration_Patterns/files/Migrate-Endpoints.html)

So, the question naturally arrives, is it even possible to do it with Apache Camel? If yes, how ? Can you provide some example or documentation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [load-balancer](http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html)  pattern in camel to model the scenario.

Comment: I don't get it, the load balancer doesn't seem to do what I want :S Thanks anyway!

Comment: What I meant was that using the loadbalancer's failover construct you can construct a route something like in process A :   <from uri="direct:foo"/>
   <loadBalance>
       <failover>
           <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
       </failover>
       <to uri="http://processB"/>
       <to uri="http://processC"/>
   </loadBalance>.Failover shall only happen when there comes an exception reaching processB.There is 1 more pattern that you can look into is [dynamic-router](http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html), you can have a bean decide what next endpoint to route the message.

Comment: I will search on that solution better. Thanks !